# Not able to call my functions

Tags: c++

The programming I'm doing basically asks the user for his name and his quiz scores. it will then total all quiz scores inputted by the user, count the number of quizzes inputted, and then averages them.

the issues i'm having with this is a few errors i'm getting. the first error i'm getting is "'student::add_quiz': function call missing argument list; use '&student:add_quiz' to create a pointer to member"

i am getting this exact same error for the rest of my functions as well and i don't know how to get around it as i thought i was calling it correctly. i tried to do as the error message said and use "&student", but that only created further errors and i don't think i even need to do this if i'm following my notes correctly.

the 2nd issue i'm having is a logic  issue. i'm not exactly sure how to get a grand total of scores that were inputted by the user so that i can average it. (example User total score input = 50+80+90+60+70=350)

i have an idea on how to average it, i would just do "total_score / quiz_count" but i am not exactly sure how to total user inputs in C++. would this be the correct way to total and average it?

```
//Implement a class Student.For the purpose of this exercise, a student has a name and
//a total quiz score.Supply an appropriate constructor and functions get_name(),
//add_quiz(int score), get_total_score(), and get_average_score().To compute the latter,
//you also need to store the number of quizzes that the student took.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

class Student
{

public:
void get_name();
void add_quiz(int score);
void get_total_score();
void get_average_score();

private:
    int quiz_count;
    int total_score;
    double average_score;


};
void Student::get_name()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl;
}
void Student::add_quiz(int score)
{
    cout << "enter score: " << endl;

    cin >> score;

    quiz_count++;



}
void Student:: get_average_score()
{
    average_score = total_score / quiz_count;
}

void Student:: get_total_score()
{

    cout << "Total score: " << total_score << endl;
}




int main ()
{
    Student student1;
    cout << student1.add_quiz << endl;
    cout << student1.get_name << endl;
    cout << student1.get_total_score << endl;
    cout << student1.get_average_score << endl;

return 0;


}
```

Comment: You forgot the argument list: `student1.add_quiz(something)`. Didn't the compiler tell you that? (Of course, you can't print the results of the function calls since they don't return anything; perhaps you should review the early chapters of your text book to remind yourself how functions work).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: objects/classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337839/c-objects-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the brackets: it should be `student1.get_total_score()`

Comment: You are doing the cout from within the function, there's no need to do it again.  Just do `student1.get_total_score();` not `cout student1.get_total_score() << endl;`

Comment: The alternative, which would probably be better, would be to return the value, like this:  `int Student:: get_average_score()
{
    average_score = total_score / quiz_count;
   return average_score
}`

Comment: ya, my books power point slides was telling me to do the cout statement, i got it now.

Answer (score 1):

well maybe add () to all of the functions , and initialize the object at start..

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
       void Student::add_quiz()
       {
        cout << "enter score: " << endl;
        int score;
        cin >> score;
        total_score += score;
        quiz_count++;



       }

       int main ()
       {
        Student student1;
        student1.add_quiz();
        student1.get_name();
        student1.get_total_score();
        student1.get_average_score();

        return 0;


       }
```

Comment: ehh? but people keep telling me that i dont need the cout statements...

Comment: I forgot to remove them, yes you dont need it.

Comment: ok gotcha. but the only error im getting now is that student1.addquiz(); is getting the error of "to few arguments in funcntion call"

"'Student::add_quiz' : function does not take 0 arguments
"

Comment: check the add_quiz() method I added, you don't have to send parameter in it. Use the one I posted, should work.

Comment: And to get a reasonable average score, you should call add_quiz() several times.